# Is it UB to mutate &T through a *mut T in unsafe rust?

Tags: rust

```rust
let r = 42;
unsafe {
    let p = &r as *const i32 as *mut i32;
    *p += 1;
}
println!("{}", r);
```

Is the above code `UB`? Is there a chance `rustc` (while assuming `r` is a `&i32`) would optimize this in a way that will end up as `UB`?

What about this ↓

```rust
let rc = Rc::new(42);
unsafe {
    let p = &*rc as *const i32 as *mut i32;
    *p += 1;
}
println!("{}", rc);
```

Rc is a [single-threaded](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) reference-counting pointer, therefore it's not thread safe.
Assuming the above is executed in a single thread, could it end up as `UB`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both cases are definitely UB.

The main problem here is the fact that any changes to the value behind the shared reference are illegal, with the exception of `UnsafeCell` internal values. The compiler can easily optimize away the change in first case and just substitute `r` into `println` call.

The second case is a bit more tricky, but it is based on the same fact. Note that the expression `&*r`, where `r` is of type `Rc<T>`, is of type &T ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7bd09f54896324bb7e0fc4780c26a75a)):

```
use std::rc::Rc;

fn test<T>(r: Rc<T>) {
    let _: () = &*r; // error: expected (), found &T
}
```

The trick is in the fact that `Rc<T>` derefs to `T`, so `*r` has type `T`.

So, it is again the immutable reference being treated as mutable.

Comment: No the compiler won't be able to inline `r` into println call, simply because we have a pointer to `r` used later.

Comment: "Immutable references used as mutable" is illegal but not necessary UB. Think of how RefCell is implemented? basically treating immutable memory as mutable.

Comment: RefCell uses UnsafeCell internally. See: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html

Comment: "we have a pointer to r used later" - but we can use it only for reading (from the compiler's point of view), since as the same time we have an immutable reference alive.